# Converting unicode list to string of list

Tags: python, list, unicode, python-2.x

I have a list of list unicode. And now I need to convert it to list of list string. How can I do that?

```
listoflist = [
    [
        u'keep', u'see', u'recover', u'try', u'cry', u'say', u'seem',
        u'come', u'saw', u'have', u'be', u'begin', u'fell', u'wait',
        u'come', u'wait', u'be', u'retire', u'be'
    ],
    [
        u'make', u'let', u'forget', u'forgive', u'punish', u'take', u'be',
        u'take', u'forget', u'come', u'think', u'say', u'be', u'be', u'say',
        u'think', u'jump', u'poke', u'come', u'be', u'have', u'try', u'come',
        u'turn', u'approach', u'be', u'meet', u'try', u'run', u'boast',
        u'bring', u'satisfy', u'use', u'be', u'leave', u'be', u'do', u'say',
        u'bristle'
    ]
]
```

I tried to use the `ast` library

```
import ast
d = []
for i in range(0,50):
    d.append([item.encode('ascii') for item in ast.literal_eval(listoflist)])
```

But i get the following error.

```
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Different approaches are welcome.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? You should **always** mention the Python version with Unicode questions, since the way Unicode is handled in Python 3 is quite different to how it's handled in Python 2.

Comment: @PM2Ring I see. Yes I am using python version 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will return `d` as an array of arrays with ascii strings instead of unicode.

```
# Iterate through each list in listoflist
# Then iterate through each unicode string in listoflist

d = [[s.encode('ascii') for s in list] for list in listoflist]
```

Also as @pm-2ring mentioned, you can also use `s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` if you would like to ignore `unicode` strings that cannot be converted to `ascii`.

To get each list we use. `for list in listoflist`.

To get each unicode string we use. `for s in list`.

Then to convert we use `s.encode('ascii')`

Comment: @KevinOelen: Also, you can do `x.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` if you want it to ignore Unicode stuff that can't be converted to ASCII. Please see the docs for [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your code understandable, do this

```
for l in listoflist:
    d_temp = []
    for s in l:
        d_temp.append(s.encode('ascii'))
    d.append(d_temp)
```

Comment: This is more easier to understand. But seems iterating through list of list is more time saving way. Thanks btw.